# Facebook advertising: the CooldownStartTime field can not be changed to be in the past

Tags: advertising, facebook

Trying to setup a conversion campaign with split testing here. Next day I return to my laptop, to see this error:

> Fix 1 error in 1 ad
>
> Time fields can only be changed to a date that is in the future.: The
> CooldownStartTime field can not be changed to be in the past.
> (#1840012)

[image]

Have no idea where it comes from. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the start date for the campaign to at least 30 minutes after the current time. So if it is 3:00 PM PST where you are you need to change the start time of the campaign to 3:30 PM PST

It might help to refresh the page as well!